# What can possibly go wrong when I try to destroy a loader again and again if it is not created

Tags: java, android

I have a code to destroy a loader .

```
 if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(1)!=null)
    {
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(1);
        Log.d("Inside", "loader one");
    }
    if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(2)!=null)
    {
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(2);
        Log.d("Inside", "loader two");
    }
    if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(3)!=null)
    {
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(3);
        Log.d("Inside", "loader three");
    }
```

What could possibly go wrong when i try to destroy it with out checking it is `null`  or not?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: actually i am using the loader to do some database queries . When i was not destroying this loader then my executequery() works fine (which give me result set) . After i tried to destroy this executequery() gives me null . It is unexpected , It comes unexpectedly . It may be the reason or it may not be the reason